# Insert data into an existing table from a CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I have a table, `blog`, with 3 columns.

```
| id | post_category | post_tags
--------------------------------
| 1  | NULL          | example
```

And I have a `categories.csv` file, following a similar format:

```
1, "News"
```

---

I want to insert **"News"** where **id=1** into the table. However the CSV file is **+100 rows long**. So how do I loop through and do this?

---

**IMPORTANT: The CSV file does have multiple references to the same ID, but with different category names. These need to be seperated by ","**

### Table (result)

```
| id | post_category | post_tags
--------------------------------
| 1  | "News, Shoes" | Shoes
```

### CSV (file)

```
id, post_category
1, "News"
1, "Shoes"
```

Comment: _The CSV file does have multiple references to the same ID, but with different category names. These need to be seperated by ","_ **Database design error**

Comment: Once you've normalised your schema, it would probably be simplest to dump the csv into MySQL, and then parse it from there.

Comment: You could use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to insert the entire .csv (very quickly) into a temporary table, and then insert from the temporary table to the desired table with your where clauses, then drop the temporary table. This would be faster than looping through each row in the .csv 

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-use-mysql-fast-load-data-for-updates-1753.html

Answer (score 0):

You could at first parse the CSV file and create an array that is indexed by an ID and the values are arrays of categories, corresponding to the IDs. Then you run through this array and execute the SQL queries (our just output them).

```
$fp = fopen("./file.csv", "r"); # insert path to CSV file here
$categories = [];
$firstLine = TRUE;
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
  if ($firstLine) { # skip first line of CSV file with header
    $firstLine = FALSE;
    continue;
  }
  if (count($line) < 2)
    continue;
  if (!isset($categories($line[0]))
    $categories[$line[0]] = [];
  $categories[$line[0]][] = $line[1];
}
fclose($fp);
foreach ($categories as $id => $v) {
  echo "INSERT INTO `blog`(`id`, `post_category`)
        VALUES (".$id.", '".implode(', ', $v)."';<br>";
}
```

But I would suggest modifying your database layout so you don't store multiple values separated by commas in a single column.